# How to get the information from a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return

Here is my code:

```
int *myFunction()
{
    int A[3] = {1,2,3};
    return A;             //this will return the pointer to the first element in the array A
}

int main (void)
{
    int A[3];

    A = myfunction();     //A gets the return value of myFunction

    for(int j=0; j==2; j++)
    {
        B[j] = 2* A[j];   //doubles each value in the array
    }
    printf("%d",B);
    return 0;      
}
```

But this does not work because the A that is returned is not the actual vector. How do I get the actual vector {1,2,3} in the main function?

Comment: You can't do this because `A` is local to `myFunction` and it will run out of scope when `myFunction` ends, leaving `main` with an invalid pointer. (Also you didn't declare `A` in `main`.)

Comment: Try returning the address of A `&A` and then use it outside the method.

Comment: Also beware that your `for` loop never runs because `j == 2` is false on the first iteration. You probably meant `j != 2`, though `j < 3` would be nicer (more common as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `myFunction` allocates `A`, but this allocation only exists within the [***scope***](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/zexscope_c.htm) of the function. When the function returns the memory holding `A` is destroyed. This means that the function is returning a pointer to memory that has not been un-allocated.

The problem is that the variable `A` does not persist outside the function. You could use a global variable or pass a pointer to the buffer into `myFunction`

**Global variable method:**

```
static int A[3];

int* myFunction()
{
    A[0] = 1; A[1] = 2; //etc
    return A;
}
```

In this example, because `A` is a global, the memory pointed to by `A` persists throught your program's entire life time. Therefore it is safe to return a pointer to it...

As a side note, global variables should probably not be used in this way... it's a little clunky. The use of the `static` keyword means that `A` will not be accessible outside of this module (C file).

**Pointer method:**

```
void myFunction(a[3])
{
    a[0] = 1; a[1] = 2; //etc
}

int main()
{
    myA[3];
    myFunction(myA);
    // and continue to print array...
}
```

In this example the `main()` function allocates `myA`. This variable exists whilst the function is executing (it's an [***automatic variable***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable)). A pointer to the array is passed into the function, which fills the array. Therefore the `main()` function can get information from `myFunction()`.

Another way to make the variable `myA` persist would be to allocate it on the heap. To do this you would do something like `int *myA = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUMBER_OF_INTS_IN_ARRAY`. This memory will then persist until you specifically desctroy it using `free()` or you program ends.

Comment: “Scope” is the wrong term; the scope of the identifier used inside the function is not a problem. The lifetime of the object is the problem. You can use an object outside of the scope of its identifier, as when its address is passed to a completely different routine. You cannot use an object after its lifetime ends. Scope is a compile-time property of identifiers. Lifetime is a run-time property of objects. E.g., the sentence “The problem is that the variable `A` does not persist outside the function.” should be “The problem is that the object `A` does not persist after function execution.”

Answer (score 1):

`int A[3] = {1,2,3};` is being created on the stack, this is, it is a local array and it's memory can be used again after `myFunction` executes.  You have to either make `int A[3]` `static` within `myFunction` or by placing it outside of all functions.  Another option would be to create `int A[3]` within `main` and pass the address of `A` to `myFunction` so `myFunction` can directly modify the contents of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

As is, your code isn't close to working anyway... your `for` loop is broken, you have undefined variables in `main`, you have function name mismatches, and your print isn't going to do what you want anyway...

The big problem as that you've got undefined behavior going on, you can't access `A[]` outside of the function where it was locally defined. The easiest way to rectify that is to use dynamic memory, `malloc()` some memory for `A` in your `myFunction` then use the values in `main` and `free()` the memory when you're done.

Here's the example fixing your other syntax issues:

```
int *myFunction()
{
    int *A;
    A = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    A[0] = 1;
    A[1] = 2;
    A[2] = 3;
    return A;
}

int main (void)
{
    int *A = myFunction();     //A gets the return value of myFunction
    int B[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        B[j] = 2* A[j];   //doubles each value in the array
    }
    free(A);
    printf("%d",B[0]);
    return 0;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array to be filled as argument to the initisliser function along with its size:

```
size_t myFunction(int * A, size_t s)
{
  int A_tmp[3] = {1,2,3};

  size_t i = 0;
  for (; i < s && i < sizeof(A_tmp)/sizeof(A_tmp[0]); ++i)
  {
    A[i] = A_tmp[i];
  }

  return i;
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
int main()
{
  int myA[3];
  size_t s = sizeof(myA)/sizeof(myA[0]);
  size_t n = myFunction(myA, s);
  if (n < s)
    fprintf(stderr, "Caution: Only the first %zu of %zu elements of A were initialised.\n", n, s);

  // and continue to print array...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*myFunction(void))[3]
{
    static int A[3] = {1,2,3};
    return &A;
}

int main (void){
    int (*A)[3], B[3];

    A = myFunction();

    for(int j=0; j<=2; j++)
    {
        B[j] = 2 * (*A)[j];
    }
    for(int j=0; j<3;++j)
        printf("%d ", B[j]);
    return 0;
}
```